# How to solve $2\cdot (2x-1)^\frac13=x^3+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This was one of the questions in my entry exam and I couldn't manage to solve it. I struggled with this equation for more than an hour,  so I'd like a direct solution instead of hints please.

$$2\cdot (2x-1)^\frac13=x^3+1$$